# Using the && operator in a character class

Tags: javascript, ruby, regex

Something like this works in Ruby but not in Javascript:

```
str = "now is the time"
p str.gsub(/[a-z&&[^aeiou]]/, '*')
```

Notice the `&&` on the second line.

`[a-z&&[^aeiou]]` works but if you remove the `[]` around the whole regex and have `a-z&&[^aeiou]` it won't work. Why? Is this unique to Ruby only? I haven't been able to find much info about this feature.

Comment: This looks like a question about JavaScript rather than Ruby, but is tagged as Ruby.

Comment: Um the code included is Ruby, so I don't see a reason to exclude the 'ruby' tag.

Comment: It wasn't even tagged as JavaScript when I wrote the comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regular expressions `&&` is the operator for character class intersection. Ruby's regex engine is called [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/), here's an excerpt from the docs (emphasis added):

> Character class
>
> ^...    negative class (lowest precedence operator)
>     x-y     range from x to y
>     [...]   set (character class in character class)
>   **..&&..  intersection (low precedence at the next of ^)**

As to why it doesn't work in JS I don't know, probably because the engine in question doesn't implement this operator. In Java for example it works.

Answer (score 2):

> A character class may contain another character class. By itself this isn’t useful because `[a-z[0-9]]` describes the same set as `[a-z0-9]`. However, character classes also support the `&&` operator which performs set intersection on its arguments. The two can be combined as follows:
>
> ```
> /[a-w&&[^c-g]z]/ # ([a-w] AND ([^c-g] OR z))
> ```
>
> This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> /[abh-w]/
> ```
>
> http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes

This operator is indeed not available in Javascript.